# In polars select all column ending with pattern and add new columns without pattern

Tags: python, calculated-columns, python-polars

I have the following dataframe:

```py
import polars as pl
import numpy as np

df = pl.DataFrame({
    "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
    "names_A0": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", None],
    "random_A0": np.random.rand(5),
    "A_A2": [True, True, False, False, False],
})
digit = 0
```

For each column X whose name ends with the string `suf =f'_A{digit}'`, I want to add an identical column to `df`, whose name is the same as X, but without `suf`.

In the example, I need to add columns `names` and `random` to the original dataframe `df`, whose content is identical to that of columns `names_A0` and `random_A0` respectively.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can you Polars Selectors along with some basic strings operations to accomplish this.
Depending on what you how you expect this problem to evolve, you can jump straight to
regular expressions, or use polars.selectors.ends_with/string.removesuffix

### String Suffix Operations

This approach uses

```
- polars.selectors.ends_with # find columns ending with string
- string.removesuffix        # remove suffix from end of string
```

translating to

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import selectors as cs
import numpy as np
import re
from functools import partial

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names_A0": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", None],
        "random_A0": np.random.rand(5),
        "A_A2": [True, True, False, False, False],
    }
)
digit = 0
suffix = f'_A{digit}'

print(
    # keep original A0 columns
    df.with_columns(
        cs.ends_with(suffix).name.map(lambda s: s.removesuffix(suffix))
    ),
    # shape: (5, 6)
    # ┌──────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┐
    # │ nrs  ┆ names_A0 ┆ random_A0 ┆ A_A2  ┆ names ┆ random   │
    # │ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
    # │ i64  ┆ str      ┆ f64       ┆ bool  ┆ str   ┆ f64      │
    # ╞══════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
    # │ 1    ┆ foo      ┆ 0.713324  ┆ true  ┆ foo   ┆ 0.713324 │
    # │ 2    ┆ ham      ┆ 0.980031  ┆ true  ┆ ham   ┆ 0.980031 │
    # │ 3    ┆ spam     ┆ 0.242768  ┆ false ┆ spam  ┆ 0.242768 │
    # │ null ┆ egg      ┆ 0.528783  ┆ false ┆ egg   ┆ 0.528783 │
    # │ 5    ┆ null     ┆ 0.583206  ┆ false ┆ null  ┆ 0.583206 │
    # └──────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┘


    # drop original A0 columns
    df.select(
        ~cs.ends_with(suffix),
        cs.ends_with(suffix).name.map(lambda s: s.removesuffix(suffix))
    ),
    # shape: (5, 4)
    # ┌──────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┐
    # │ nrs  ┆ A_A2  ┆ names ┆ random   │
    # │ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
    # │ i64  ┆ bool  ┆ str   ┆ f64      │
    # ╞══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
    # │ 1    ┆ true  ┆ foo   ┆ 0.713324 │
    # │ 2    ┆ true  ┆ ham   ┆ 0.980031 │
    # │ 3    ┆ false ┆ spam  ┆ 0.242768 │
    # │ null ┆ false ┆ egg   ┆ 0.528783 │
    # │ 5    ┆ false ┆ null  ┆ 0.583206 │
    # └──────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┘

    sep='\n\n'
)
```

### Regular Expressions

Alternatively you can use regular expressions to detect a range of suffix patterns

```
- polars.selectors.matches  # find columns matching a pattern
- re.sub                    # substitute in string based on pattern
```

We will need to ensure our pattern ends with a `'$'` to anchor the pattern
to the end of the string.

```py
import polars as pl
from polars import selectors as cs
import numpy as np
import re
from functools import partial

df = pl.DataFrame(
    {
        "nrs": [1, 2, 3, None, 5],
        "names_A0": ["foo", "ham", "spam", "egg", None],
        "random_A0": np.random.rand(5),
        "A_A2": [True, True, False, False, False],
    }
)
digit=0
suffix = fr'_A{digit}$'

print(
    # keep original A0 columns
    df.with_columns(
        cs.matches(suffix).name.map(lambda s: re.sub(suffix, '', s))
    ),
    # shape: (5, 6)
    # ┌──────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┐
    # │ nrs  ┆ names_A0 ┆ random_A0 ┆ A_A2  ┆ names ┆ random   │
    # │ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
    # │ i64  ┆ str      ┆ f64       ┆ bool  ┆ str   ┆ f64      │
    # ╞══════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
    # │ 1    ┆ foo      ┆ 0.713324  ┆ true  ┆ foo   ┆ 0.713324 │
    # │ 2    ┆ ham      ┆ 0.980031  ┆ true  ┆ ham   ┆ 0.980031 │
    # │ 3    ┆ spam     ┆ 0.242768  ┆ false ┆ spam  ┆ 0.242768 │
    # │ null ┆ egg      ┆ 0.528783  ┆ false ┆ egg   ┆ 0.528783 │
    # │ 5    ┆ null     ┆ 0.583206  ┆ false ┆ null  ┆ 0.583206 │
    # └──────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┘


    # drop original A0 columns
    df.select(
        ~cs.matches(suffix),
        cs.matches(suffix).name.map(lambda s: re.sub(suffix, '', s))
    ),
    # shape: (5, 4)
    # ┌──────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┐
    # │ nrs  ┆ A_A2  ┆ names ┆ random   │
    # │ ---  ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
    # │ i64  ┆ bool  ┆ str   ┆ f64      │
    # ╞══════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
    # │ 1    ┆ true  ┆ foo   ┆ 0.713324 │
    # │ 2    ┆ true  ┆ ham   ┆ 0.980031 │
    # │ 3    ┆ false ┆ spam  ┆ 0.242768 │
    # │ null ┆ false ┆ egg   ┆ 0.528783 │
    # │ 5    ┆ false ┆ null  ┆ 0.583206 │
    # └──────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┘

    sep='\n\n'
)
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use polars' [column selectors](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/selectors.html) to select the corresponding columns and then use [`.name.map`](https://docs.pola.rs/py-polars/html/reference/expressions/api/polars.Expr.name.map.html) to rename the output of the selector expression.

```py
import polars.selectors as cs

df.with_columns(cs.matches(f"_A{digit}$").name.map(lambda name: name[:-3]))
```

```
shape: (5, 6)
┌──────┬──────────┬───────────┬───────┬───────┬──────────┐
│ nrs  ┆ names_A0 ┆ random_A0 ┆ A_A2  ┆ names ┆ random   │
│ ---  ┆ ---      ┆ ---       ┆ ---   ┆ ---   ┆ ---      │
│ i64  ┆ str      ┆ f64       ┆ bool  ┆ str   ┆ f64      │
╞══════╪══════════╪═══════════╪═══════╪═══════╪══════════╡
│ 1    ┆ foo      ┆ 0.626253  ┆ true  ┆ foo   ┆ 0.626253 │
│ 2    ┆ ham      ┆ 0.480437  ┆ true  ┆ ham   ┆ 0.480437 │
│ 3    ┆ spam     ┆ 0.789309  ┆ false ┆ spam  ┆ 0.789309 │
│ null ┆ egg      ┆ 0.126665  ┆ false ┆ egg   ┆ 0.126665 │
│ 5    ┆ null     ┆ 0.522989  ┆ false ┆ null  ┆ 0.522989 │
└──────┴──────────┴───────────┴───────┴───────┴──────────┘
```

**Note.** In the example above, we select all columns with names that contain the string `"_A"` followed a `digit`, followed by the string end (`$`). As the suffix is guaranteed to be of length 3, the new name is equal to the original name without the last 3 letters.

Comment: nice! I think you could substitute `matches(suffix)` with `ends_with(suffix)`, couldn't you? Then this would basically become @Cameron Riddel's answer.

Comment: @DeltaIV Glad it helped and yes - there are a variety of ways to select and rename the columns!

Comment: @DeltaIV Hericks is using the regex string with `$` and the end which means end of string so either doing matches(f"{suffix}$") or ends_with(suffix) are the same thing.

Comment: They also all end up as `pl.col(f"^.*{suffix}$")` see: `cs.ends_with("foo").meta.write_json()`

Comment: @jqurious you mention `cs.ends_with("foo").meta.write_json()`. I'm not sure how this is related? Maybe you wanted to add a link?

Comment: `cs.matches("foo$")` and `cs.ends_with("foo")` get turned into `pl.col("^.*foo$")` - the meta.write_json is to let you see that their "inner representation" is the same.